# I have written a method to write any string in file. Should I close file or not

Tags: c#, file-system, logging

I have written this code to write string to file. If File is not created then create file and If created append to same file. File is created daywise.

```
public static void WriteLog(string sMessage)
            {
                try
                {
                    //string logfolderpath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileLogs_Path"].ToString(); // GetLogFolderPath();
                    string logfolderpath = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PhoenixMI"].ToString();       //GetLogFolderPath();
                    DirectoryInfo logdirFile = new DirectoryInfo(logfolderpath);
                    if (!logdirFile.Exists)
                    {
                        logdirFile.Create();
                    }
                    if (logfolderpath != "")
                    {
                        System.IO.DirectoryInfo logfolderDirectory = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(logfolderpath);
                        string filePath = logfolderDirectory.FullName;
                        string fileName = "HL7_Logs_" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "_" + DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + ".txt";
                        string sDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
                        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath,fileName)))
                        {
                            StreamWriter sw = null;
                            //Open File
                            FileStream fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
                            // generate a file stream with UTF8 characters          
                            sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                            sw.WriteLine(sDateTime + "    " + sMessage);
                            sw.Close();
                            sw = null;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StreamWriter sw = null;
                            //Open File
                            FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(filePath,fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                            // generate a file stream with UTF8 characters          
                            sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                            sw.WriteLine(sDateTime + "    " + sMessage);
                            sw.Close();
                            sw = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    WriteErrorToAppLog(ex); //Other nethos to exception in this method.
                }
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, our focus is somewhat different that Stack Overflow, since we are reviewing the code to help you improve your coding abilities and not debugging the code we like to see as much of the code as possible. It would be better to post the whole class this function belongs to including the `using` statements at the top.

Comment: Please look up the documentation for Directory.Create and File.AppendText . Look at DateTime ToString and how you can provide a custom format. Etc. Don't needlessly reinvent the wheel, first look what the framework already offers you. Also, you could have easily googled this before writing your code.

Answer (score 2):

- As it was stated by others this problem has been solved by many logging libraries

  - So, you don't need to do it yourself
- But if you want to do that by your own then here are my observations

  - Please note that my suggestions are focusing on your code
  - They are not dealing with *thread-safety* and *robustness*, but you **should**

#### Run the directory check only once

- Rather than checking each and every time the existence of a directory do it only once

  - A good candidate could be your logger's constructor
- Please prefer the `Directory` class and its `static` methods over `DirectoryInfo`
- Please throw exception if the retrieved the settings is empty rather than silently ignoring it
- Please use camelCasing for your variables

```
const string appSettingsKey = "PhoenixMI";
string logFolderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[appSettingsKey];
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(logFolderPath))
{
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(appSettingsKey, "It must be non-empty");
}

if (!Directory.Exists(logFolderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(logFolderPath);
}
```

#### Prefer string interpolation over string concatenation

```
string fileName = $"HL7_Logs_{DateTime.Now.Year}_{DateTime.Now.Month}_{DateTime.Now.Day}.txt";
...
sw.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:s}    {sMessage}");
```

#### Do not repeat yourself

- The most inner `if`-`else` blocks are differing in the `FileMode` only

  - You could simply use `Append` in both cases

```
string logFilePath = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);
    
FileStream fs = File.Open(logFilePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
sw.WriteLine(sDateTime + "    " + sMessage);
sw.Close();
sw = null;
```

#### Use using statements/declaration

- Since C# 8 you can use [using declaration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)
- `FileStream` and `StreamWriter` are disposable so prefer the `using` over explicit `Close` calls

```
using FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, fileMode, FileAccess.Write);
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

#### Put all things together

- Please prefer meaningful names for your variables
- The `WriteMessage` could be re-written like this

```
static void WriteLogMessageIntoFile(string logMessage)
{
    string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.logFolderPath);
    string fileName = $"HL7_Logs_{DateTime.Now.Year}_{DateTime.Now.Month}_{DateTime.Now.Day}.txt";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, fileName);

    try
    {
        using FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
        using StreamWriter logFileWriter = new StreamWriter(logFileStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        logFileWriter.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:s}    {logMessage}");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteErrorToAppLog(ex);
    } 
}
```

- Please note that this solution is neither thread-safe nor robust

  - It can fail if multiple threads are calling this static method nearly at the same time
  - It can fail if the message is too large
  - It logs a timestamp only if the message is null or whitespaces
  - etc.

Comment: How can I make it thread safe?

Comment: @SupRaviKumar You need to have exclusive access to the file. Most of the libraries solve this by using a thread-safe buffer. The WriteMessage adds a new entry to the buffer and a dedicated background thread emits the messages to the file from the buffer periodically or when a certain number of messages sit in the buffer.

Comment: @PeterCsala FileMode.Append ->Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file. [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=net-7.0), so the FileMode fileMode = File.Exists(logFilePath) ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create;
 is just useless

Comment: @Margon Thanks, just updated accordingly